# SQL Server Express seems to run queries much slower than SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have both SQL Server and SQL Server Express installed on my desktop PC, and have the `AdventureWorks` database installed out-of-the-box separately for each.

When I run the same application against the AW database on SQL Server Express, each query takes more than twice as long to complete. These are simple queries - not particularly demanding. None of the processor cores are under any significant load.

This has surprised me. I would expect that the (commercial) SQL Server would run faster in an enterprise environment with thousands of users: I would not expect to see any difference in performance for a single-user running a very simple set of queries on a local database.

Has anyone else had a similar experience, or can shed any light on what might be going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server Express is limited to use a single CPU and 1GB RAM, so that could be causing the queries to run slower than the paid editions.